# Add module position in full page of zoo extension

Tags: joomla, module

I want to add joomla module position in full page of zoo extension.
I have tried these codes but didn't work.
`<?php $this->renderModules( 'users-bodule' ); ?>` and `<jdoc:include type="modules" name="fixed-b" style="xhtml" />`

How I can do that?

Comment: and this <jdoc:include type="modules" name="fixed-b" style="xhtml" /> by didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

try this,

If you want to render the module from php section or via ajax something like below.

```
   $document = JFactory::getDocument();
   $renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module');

   $Module = JModuleHelper::getModule('mod_fmDataGrid');//the following section for custom param if you are not using any param simply avoid it.

   $Params = "param1=bruno\n\rparam2=chris";
   $Module->params = $Params;
   echo $renderer->render($Module);
```

Form templates simply.

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="position-0" />
```

Hope its helps..

Answer (score 1):

ZOO have native Element to insert any module in any layout you want.
Named Joomla Module (Other category).
Just insert it as any other element.
[image]